# Swiper JS carousel not working pagination and navigation in Joomla + Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, joomla, carousel, bootstrap-5, swiper.js

At first try to use Swiper JS.
I'd connected it from CDN. Using it in my Joomla 4 template, this template using Twitter Bootstrap 5.

This is link: https://club.artcolorit.com/
I need create the same, like in Figma layout: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCxEL.png)

Some problems:

1. I see navigation, but it didn't working.
2. I didn't see pagination
3. It need display 3 slide on the screen, but I see only one.

**Javascript**

```
<script>
      let swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true,
          renderBullet: function (index, className) {
            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + "</span>";
          },
        },
        navigation: {
           nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
           prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
      });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="games" class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<h2 class="zag-h2">Наши игры</h2>
<div class="swiper">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1<img src="images/game.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2<img src="images/game.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3<img src="images/game.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-pagination"> </div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"> </div>
<div class="swiper-button-next"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Help please with these problems. Thanks

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Comment: This question about Swiper JS. I'm using clear JS code and it doesn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in my code.
Script must be in the code **below** than HTML-elements of the slider. I didn't know about it.